# Search through all TODOs based on when they were added

Tags: unix, perforce

I would like to collect a list of all java files with the words containing "TODO" while filtering the amount of files that are returned to me based on when the "TODO" was added in the file.

I'd like to either use p4 or unix scripting or both. Thanks!

Comment: Is your code in version control? Like git?

Comment: This seems to be impossible, unless... see above

Comment: yes, all code is in version control. I'm using Perforce

Answer (score 2):

Use [P4 Grep](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_grep.html) for your purpose. You may have to run this as admin though based on your user access (number of row scans, timeouts etc)

Comment: And once 'p4 grep' has told you which files have 'TODO' in them, use 'p4 annotate' to figure out when the line containing 'TODO' was added. Or, use 'p4 grep -a' to search ALL revisions, and then select the oldest revision from the output.